# Eclipse does not open my workspace

Tags: android, eclipse, metadata, logfile, eclipse-metadata

I am getting this error when loading my workspace in eclipse.

```
 An error has occurred.See the log file
 D:\XXX\App_name\.metadata\.log.
```

I can able to open other workspaces and also able to create new onw.I didnt save the copy of my code.Please anyone help me?

Thanks!!!

Comment: move to your workspace folder and delete the .metadata folder and then restart again the eclipse.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333825/an-error-has-occured-please-see-log-file-eclipse-juno

Comment: In my workspace I can find only .metadata folder

Comment: Inside the configuration/.settings folder of your Eclipse installation, there is a file called org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs. Open this file in a text editor and change the property SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG from false to true.

Comment: Amiya It is in true state only

Comment: 1. Close the eclipse.
2. Try deleting the ".metadata" folder in your workspace folder.
3. Open up eclipse and re-import the project again into your workspace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for all who commented for my question.I tried your answers but I can resolve that issue by removing this folder from my .plugin folder,

```
 .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try typing the following in the console:

```
C:\path\to\eclipse\eclipse -clean
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem while running Eclipse neon with Java 9(latest). I used to get error in .metadata.log . Class not found exception.

Checked in eclipse forum and they had a know error with Java 9. Work around was to use java 8. I tried that and it worked for me. Fix should be out anytime soon.

There are other work around but i did not need it since my project required java 8 anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to add plugins via Eclipse IDE (**Help->install new software**) the problem occurs.

I suggest you to get the relevant plugin using there official website or in IDE (`Help ->Eclipse market place`).