# Multiple validations occurring with Eclipse Neon even though it is been disabled

Tags: eclipse

Im having a serious problem with Eclipse Neon and in every save/click on the file/building files it shows up validation. By referring to various blogs, the below are the set up done by me on validations. But still I have same issue. Please suggest me whether this set up is correct.

```
1) Set up done in Windows-> Preferences -> Validations
    a) Set the checkbox for 'Allow projects to override these preference settings'
    b) Set the check box for 'Suspend all validators'
    c) Rest all the check boxes are unset especially DTD validator, XML Schema Validator and XML Validator are individually deselected.
2) Build Automatically was deselected and verified, but the same situation occured. For the current set up I have enabled it again.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the below steps and got this issue resolved,

```
1) Taken help from this link: [https://github.com/nokia/RED/issues/31][1]
2) Followed this link, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333825/an-error-has-occured-please-see-log-file-eclipse-juno][1]
3) Deleted *.snap files in Java Workspace->.metadata->.plugins
4) Out of Memory Issue in Eclipse:
   a) Followed this link : [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYtH5yJRz5s @phcharbonneau@hotmail.com][1]
   b) Heap size provided: -Xms512m -Xmx1152m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m
   c) Deleted duplicate JRE files(older version)
   d) After Set Up, Restart the system.
```