# Error in the Log File of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I've searched for a solution to this problem all over stackoverflow and other sites, but I couldn't find a solution that addresses this particular error. Eclipse fails to launch, with an error in the log file which is like that :

> "An erroe has occurred. See the log file 
>   C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Apps\adt
>   bundle\adt-bundle-windows64bit\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\eclipse\configuration\1507118079036.log."

So please, can  you help me to solve this problem? ( as I am totally new to Eclipse and Java )

Comment: What is in the file C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Apps\adt bundle\adt-bundle-windows64bit\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\eclipse\configuration\1507118079036.log

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333825/an-error-has-occured-please-see-log-file-eclipse-juno visit this

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Delete the .snap file

```
   YOUR_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap
```

For example:

```
    E:\Sankalp Gupta\JAVA\JavaPractice\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\70.snap
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error in the Log File of Eclipse

Fallow these simple steps to resolve eclipse launch problem.

Step 1: Quit eclipse

Step 2: GO to your workspace and delete **.metadata** folder in your YOUR_WORKSPACE

> For example, YOUR_WORKSPACE folder like C:\Users\SamDev\workspace

Step 3: Start eclipse & Choose same **workspace** or New( You will see as a new workspace created) , It  solve your eclipse launch problem.

Comment: **Don't do this** if you don't want to lose data!

Comment: @howlger, Which kind of data you taking about, can you elaborate a little.

Comment: The `.metadata` folder contains all workspace-specific preferences (most of _Windows > Preferences_), important meta information about projects, local history, etc. It also contains temp/cached files which are not important (use `-clean` to ignore them). Any plug-in can store data in the `.metadata` folder. Therefore it depends on the plug-ins used what is stored in the the `.metadata` folder.

Comment: @howlger,I agree with you but Here according to this stackoverflow question by user, he/she totally new to Eclipse and Java and Eclipse fails to launch.

Comment: If Eclipse logs an error in the configuration area (`...\configuration\{time-stamp}.log`), it fails **before the workspace** is opened (otherwise `...\{workspace}\.metadata\.log` will be used). Here, the error would also occur with a new workspace (`-data ...`). See question: _"Eclipse fails to launch"_.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I tried the following and it resolved the issue:

1. Go to the eclipse directory.
2. Open the command prompt.
3. Run the `eclipse -clean` command.

Eclipse should work fine now.