# I want to convert my console program to a runnable JAR file

Tags: eclipse, export, executable-jar

I want to convert my java program to a runnable JAR file under Eclipse and I got this error

An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo.getText()" because "this.fDestinationNamesCombo" is null

Comment: Show us the complete stack trace

Answer (score 0):

For me deleting .metadata file works. I used below steps

Solved :

```
Quit eclipse
GO to your workspace and delete .metadata folder
Now open eclipse with same Workspace path ( You will see as a new workspace )
Now right click import > General > Existing Projects into Workspace > next > Select root directory -> browse to your current workspace and press OK.
Now you will all see your all projects and then hit OK again.
Voila, same projects with same workspace no migration or reference problem.
```

Answer copied from: [An error has occured. Please see log file - eclipse juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333825/an-error-has-occured-please-see-log-file-eclipse-juno)