# Eclipse IDE is not starting ever since I upgraded to Windows 11

Tags: java, eclipse

I was using Eclipse IDE with Oracle/Sun Java 17 for quite some time on Windows 10. Then I upgraded my Windows from 10 to 11. Ever since then, either Eclipse is taking almost 35 minutes to start(too much time as I have Intel Core I7 - 6 cores plus 64 GB RAM and SSD) to startup.

Followed these [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333825/an-error-has-occured-please-see-log-file-eclipse-juno)
and deleted entire metadata directory(C:\Users\ashus\eclipse-workspace.metadata)

And tried using eclipse - clean command to launch eclipse.
Same issue, after more than 15 minutes - I kill the javaw.exe and then get to see this error
[image]

I am using Oracle/Sun Java 17

Comment: Already tried with a just downloaded, different vendor JDK 17? Like microsoft, corretto, IBM...

Comment: On the command line, what does `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe" -version` return?

Comment: C:\Windows\System32>java --version
java 17 2021-09-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17+35-LTS-2724)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-LTS-2724, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Does `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe" -version` return the same?

Comment: I couldn't find what Eclipse version you are using. The latest version, i.e. 2023-03, comes with JDK 17 as part of the distribution. How do you know that your Eclipse is using Oracle/Sun Java 17? Maybe post the contents of your `eclipse.ini` file. By the way, have you looked at the contents of the Eclipse log files?

Comment: Eclipse should start on that kind of hardware in about 4 seconds. If you don't have a 'boot with default workspace' setting enabled, 1 second for the 'select workspace' dialog to show. In your eclipse installation there is also `eclipsec.exe`. Open a terminal (`cmd.exe`, for example), and run eclipsec.exe. This will give you way more output to try to debug this problem.

Comment: To be clear, the image you pasted is _useless_ - that is simply javaw correctly reporting it got killed by your explicit action. Other than trying to glean your settings from this screenshot, it doesn't add anything meaningful. Paste the output of eclipsec (_before_ explicitly killing javaw), and paste the contents of `eclipse.ini`.

Comment: 'Oracle/Sun java 17' isn't a thing. Did you mean Oracle's commercial JDK17 offering (I doubt that), or team OpenJDK's java17 release, which is no longer supported? It is unlikely to be the problem here, but, it further highlights how this question doesn't include the information required to answer it.

Comment: 2021-09 is over a year old, and 6 (nearly 7) releases back. Reinstall with the current release.

Comment: @rzwitserloot you wrote (in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76390851/eclipse-ide-is-not-starting-ever-since-i-upgraded-to-windows-11#comment134704386_76390851)): _or team OpenJDK's java17 release, which is no longer supported_ Not according to [this](https://endoflife.date/java) - or am I incorrectly interpreting what is written on that webpage?

Comment: @Abra The OpenJDK project itself release reference binaries for the first release and two maintenance releases, when Java 18 was released, they stopped releasing binaries for Java 17. If you want to have **supported** binaries of Java 17, you need to use binaries from one of the vendors, like Oracle, Eclipse Adoptium, Microsoft, Azul, etc.

Comment: @Abra Yes, you are incorrectly interpreting what is written on that webpage. The LTS schema is __not__ written in any spec, and is merely the support Oracle offers for their own Oracle (commercial!) JDK release, _not_ the OpenJDK non-commercial release (which is also released by oracle). Every entity that compiles and packages up the OpenJDK source gets to pick their own. In practice, __all__ shippers treat Oracle's LTS list as their own LTS list, __but__, Oracle's OpenJDK non-com release __does not__ and has no LTS releases whatsoever. New version out? Old version no longer maintained.

Answer (score 1):

I started facing a similar issue in Windows 11. I do a fresh installation every time, and the Eclipse stops working after a couple of days/weeks. My observation is Eclipse relies on the jars which get copies in the temporary directory area
example being

`C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\eoiAD10.tmp\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\106\data\-551955967\plugins`
I believe windows 11 somehow cleans up these directories.
You can find this path in config.ini in your Eclipse installation. The last time I backed up the plugin directory to nontemp area and updated the config.ini to use this path, I faced the same issue again after a few days. However, I had the backup of the original path and populated it back from the backup. It works fine. I know it is a hack, but a small batch file to repopulate when you face an issue can be a quick solution.